# Using a space character in javascript and crossfilter

Tags: javascript, json, filter, crossfilter

I currently have a json file with the value 'MIME type: "image/jpeg"' however when I try and filter on the MIME type I've ran into a problem because it contains a space.

Anything involving a '\' causes a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Leaving in the space cases a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Code for reference (problem code commented)

```
<script>
$.getJSON("/static/data.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var files = crossfilter(data);

    var n = files.groupAll().reduceCount().value();
    console.log("There are " + n + " files present.")

    var typeDimension = files.dimension(function(d) { return d.MIME type; }); // The return statement here
    typeDimension.filter("image/jpeg")
    var jpg = files.groupAll().reduceCount().value();
    console.log("There are " + jpg + " JPEG images in this set of files")

    typeDimension.filterAll()


});
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: This is basic JS syntax. Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

`d.MIME type` is indeed a syntax error. You need `d["MIME type"]`.